# How can you choose which speakers to play audio to in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, audio, actionscript

How can you select a certain set of speakers to play audio to in ActionScript 3.0?  Is this even possible, or does it invariably use the default device?  [The SoundTransform class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html#methodSummary) doesn't seem to help very much...

Comment: This seems to be the problem of Flash player not having access to any kind of hardware selection. So, I think there's no way to do this.

Comment: It's able to select mics and cameras though, but I've never seen any mention of selecting the speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this posting on the Adobe forums, it is not possible to even list the devices available: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/980974